# Retornar objeto javascript

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, funções

```js
var Mensagem = function(opcoes){
 var padrao = {
     titutlo: "",     
        msg: "",
        lido: false
    }
    var config = $.extend(padrao, opcoes);
    
    this.prototype = config;
}

var msg = new Mensagem({
 titulo: "Olá mundo!",
    msg : "Testando..."
});
console.info("Retorno:");
console.log(msg);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Retorno no console
```

Queria que este código retornasse

> { titulo:"valor", msg: "valor", lido: "valor" }

mas está retornando

```
{ 
    prototype:{ titulo:"valor", msg: "valor", lido: "valor" }  
}
```

O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que borrada que eu fiz, bastava apenas colocar um return!

```js
var Mensagem = function(opcoes){
 var padrao = {
     titutlo: "",     
        msg: "",
        lido: false
    }
    var config = $.extend(padrao, opcoes);
    
   return config;
}

var msg = new Mensagem({
 titulo: "Olá mundo!",
    msg : "Testando..."
});
console.info("Retorno:");
console.log(msg);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Retorno no console!
```

Comment: Acontece colega, as vezes temos tanta certeza que fizemos certo, que uma virgula mata nosso código kkk O melhor é refrescar a cabeça e mexer depois.

Answer (score -4):

Tenta:
console.log(msg.prototype);